# fetch one record every n minute in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table named 'DataLogTable' in which data are coming every 5 second. Now i want to get only one record for every 1 minute, 5 minute, 15 minutes and 30 minutes. For this i used following code

```
Declare @intv int=5  
        --select 'minute',@intv
        SELECT 
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),DATEANDTIME,113)  DATETIME, ALARM, F870 'COLD JUICE PRE [PSI]', F872 'COLD WATER PRE [PSI]', F82 'FILLER TEMP [DEGC]' , F810 'FLOW [LTR/MIN]', F869 'HOT JUICE PRE[PSI]', F874 'HOT WATER PRE[PSI]', F867 'HOT WATER TEMP[DEGC]', F84'JUICE TEMP AFTER HOLD TUBE[DEGC]', F822'PD FOR COLD PHE[PSI]', F821'PD FOR HOT PHE[PSI]', F8X'PHE INLET TEMP[DEGC]', B1 'MACHINE 1 STATUS', B2'MACHINE 2 STATUS' FROM
        (
            SELECT DATEANDTIME,
              NULL ALARM, F870 F870, F872 F872, F82 F82, F810 F810, F869 F869, F874 F874, F867 F867, F84 F84, F822 F822, F821 F821, F8X F8X, CASE WHEN B1=1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END B1, CASE WHEN B2=1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END B2
            FROM DATALOGTABLE WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE  (CONVERT(DATE,DATEANDTIME,103)>=CONVERT(DATE,@FROMDATETIME,103) AND CONVERT(DATE,DATEANDTIME,103)<=CONVERT(DATE,@TODATETIME,103))
            AND (((DATEPART(minute,dateandtime)%@intv)=0) and (DATEPART(SECOND,dateandtime)>58))            
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEANDTIME, ALARMTXT ALARM,
            NULL F870, NULL F872, NULL F82, NULL F810, NULL F869, NULL F874, NULL F867, NULL F84, 
            NULL F822, NULL F821, NULL F8X, NULL B1, NULL B2
            FROM DBO.ALARMHISTORY WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE (CONVERT(DATE,DATEANDTIME,103)>=CONVERT(DATE,@FROMDATETIME,103) AND CONVERT(DATE,DATEANDTIME,103)<=CONVERT(DATE,@TODATETIME,103))
            AND (((DATEPART(minute,dateandtime)%@intv)=0) and (DATEPART(SECOND,dateandtime)>58))
        )Z ORDER BY Z.DATEANDTIME DESC
```

For example i have records as

```
dateAndtime               F870   F872   F82     F810    F869    F874    F867    F84     F822    F821    F8X     B1  B2  
2020-01-09 18:37:16.593   0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 18:39:23.660   70.00  0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 18:39:38.470   70.00  72.00  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 18:40:06.693   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 18:41:40.237   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 18:42:15.243   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 18:42:48.090   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1   0   
2020-01-09 18:44:28.390   0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 18:53:37.693   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 19:18:54.333   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 19:20:11.367   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 19:20:12.333   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 19:20:13.350   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0
```

following the above if i want to view only one record for every 5 minute then it is showing records where minutes are divisible by 5 as :-

```
dateAndtime               F870   F872   F82     F810    F869    F874    F867    F84     F822    F821    F8X     B1  B2  

2020-01-09 18:40:06.693   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0
2020-01-09 18:53:37.693   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 19:20:11.367   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0
```

But output should be

```
dateAndtime               F870   F872   F82     F810    F869    F874    F867    F84     F822    F821    F8X     B1  B2  
2020-01-09 18:37:16.593   0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 18:42:48.090   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1   0   
2020-01-09 18:53:37.693   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0   
2020-01-09 19:18:54.333   70.00  72.00  2.00    0.00    69.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0   0
```

Here the first record is at datetime '2020-01-09 18:37:16.593' will not come as it's minute is not divisible by 5. how to solve this. i am stuck here.

Comment: Add the expected results to your question.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to show the first row that is at least 5 minutes after the previous row?

Comment: yes sir  In the above case two adjacent row should have difference of 5 minute. Also two adjacent row should have difference of 1 minute, 5 minute, 15 minutes and 30 minutes whichever is given.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` (or alternatively `RANK()` to identify the first row within each interval. I made an attempt at modifying your original query, using `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` for the interval calculation based on the first qualifying row, but this is not been tested since you didn't include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in your question.

```
Declare @intv int=5;  
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),DATEANDTIME,113) DATETIME
            , ALARM
            , F870 'COLD JUICE PRE [PSI]'
            , F872 'COLD WATER PRE [PSI]'
            , F82 'FILLER TEMP [DEGC]'
            , F810 'FLOW [LTR/MIN]'
            , F869 'HOT JUICE PRE[PSI]'
            , F874 'HOT WATER PRE[PSI]'
            , F867 'HOT WATER TEMP[DEGC]'
            , F84 'JUICE TEMP AFTER HOLD TUBE[DEGC]'
            , F822 'PD FOR COLD PHE[PSI]'
            , F821 'PD FOR HOT PHE[PSI]'
            , F8X 'PHE INLET TEMP[DEGC]'
            , B1 'MACHINE 1 STATUS'
            , B2 'MACHINE 2 STATUS' 
            , DATEANDTIME
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, (SELECT MIN(dateAndtime) FROM DATALOGTABLE WHERE dateAndTime >= @FROMDATETIME AND dateAndTime <= @TODATETIME), dateAndtime)/@intv*@intv), (SELECT MIN(dateAndtime) FROM DATALOGTABLE WHERE dateAndTime >= @FROMDATETIME AND dateAndTime <= @TODATETIME)) ORDER BY dateAndtime) AS RowNum
        FROM (
            SELECT DATEANDTIME,
              NULL ALARM, F870 F870, F872 F872, F82 F82, F810 F810, F869 F869, F874 F874, F867 F867, F84 F84, F822 F822, F821 F821, F8X F8X, CASE WHEN B1=1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END B1, CASE WHEN B2=1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END B2
            FROM DATALOGTABLE WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE  (CONVERT(DATE,DATEANDTIME,103)>=CONVERT(DATE,@FROMDATETIME,103) AND CONVERT(DATE,DATEANDTIME,103)<=CONVERT(DATE,@TODATETIME,103))
            AND (((DATEPART(minute,dateandtime)%@intv)=0) and (DATEPART(SECOND,dateandtime)>58))            
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEANDTIME, ALARMTXT ALARM,
            NULL F870, NULL F872, NULL F82, NULL F810, NULL F869, NULL F874, NULL F867, NULL F84, 
            NULL F822, NULL F821, NULL F8X, NULL B1, NULL B2
            FROM DBO.ALARMHISTORY WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE (CONVERT(DATE,DATEANDTIME,103)>=CONVERT(DATE,@FROMDATETIME,103) AND CONVERT(DATE,DATEANDTIME,103)<=CONVERT(DATE,@TODATETIME,103))
            AND (((DATEPART(minute,dateandtime)%@intv)=0) and (DATEPART(SECOND,dateandtime)>58))
            ) Z
)
SELECT
              "DATETIME"
            , "ALARM"
            , "COLD JUICE PRE [PSI]"
            , "COLD WATER PRE [PSI]"
            , "FILLER TEMP [DEGC]"
            , "FLOW [LTR/MIN]"
            , "HOT JUICE PRE[PSI]"
            , "HOT WATER PRE[PSI]"
            , "HOT WATER TEMP[DEGC]"
            , "JUICE TEMP AFTER HOLD TUBE[DEGC]"
            , "PD FOR COLD PHE[PSI]"
            , "PD FOR HOT PHE[PSI]"
            , "PHE INLET TEMP[DEGC]"
            , "MACHINE 1 STATUS"
            , "MACHINE 2 STATUS"
WHERE RowNum = 1
ORDER BY DATEANDTIME DESC;
```

Comment: In the current scenario interval is 5 minute. Following your query will return those values whose minutes is divisible by 5. But the entry in the table has datetime '2020-01-09 18:37:16.593' and its minutes i.e. 37 is not divisible by 5, so it will not come following your query. so, your query is not giving appropriate result.

Comment: @SunnySandeep, I overlooked removing this `WHERE` criteria from your original query. Try removing it to see if you get the desired results: `AND (((DATEPART(minute,dateandtime)%@intv)=0) and (DATEPART(SECOND,dateandtime)>58))`